# Trying to find a word similar to apex but ending with -muth

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that I've heard of that ends with -muth and has a meaning similar to apex or the very high point of something. I could have sworn that I've heard this word before. It is possible that it doesn't mean what I thought it means but I would like to know what it is regardless.

I looked up synonyms for apex [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/apex) but the word I'm thinking of doesn't show up.

Comment: azimuth. :) is the word. But it is not the same meaning at all.

Comment: @Lambie What the..? That was the word but it totally didn't mean what I thought it meant. Anyways thanks a billion. That was driving me crazy.

Comment: zenith might work for you if you want a th at the end.

Comment: Happens to me all the time. Looks like a duck, walks like a duck, but ain't no duck. :)

Comment: Well, it's not *bismuth*, so that leaves only one other possibility for words ending in *-muth* in English — and *altazimuth* doesn’t count as a compound. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're probably thinking of *azimuth,* but that's simply a direction at a particular angle.

> The direction of a celestial object from the observer, expressed as the angular distance from the north or south point of the horizon to the point at which a vertical circle passing through the object intersects the horizon.
>
> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/azimuth)]

The highest point in the sky, similar to *apex,* is **zenith.**

> The point in the sky or celestial sphere directly above an observer.
>   The opposite of *nadir*.
>
> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/zenith)]